# Proguard, Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel kotlin

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-proguard

I'm getting that error only when minifyEnabled is true (even with -dontobfuscate)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.myapps.app.TracksVM
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:202)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:135)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:103)
        at com.myapps.app.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.kt:72)
```

ViewModelProvider.java:202 in the support library source refers to:

```
try {
                    return modelClass.getConstructor(Application.class).newInstance(mApplication);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of " + modelClass, e);
                }
```

Proguard probably removed a method or the constructor?

Here's my proguard.pro:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-dontobfuscate
```

The ViewModel:

```
class TracksVM(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
...
}
```

And the Fragment:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: TracksVM

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_recents, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TracksVM::class.java)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing viewModelProviderFactory -

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelProvidersFactory).get(TracksVM::class.java)
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: How do I do that without dagger and @inject?

Comment: ohh sorry ...I thought you are using dagger.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following rule is missing in the consumer Proguard rules for the android lifecycle aar:

```
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class * extends android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel {
    <init>(android.app.Application);
}
```

When using the latest version (androidx?) it should be fixed afaik.